# Express infinite serie in terms of a shape parameters of beta distribution

Tags: probability, beta-binomial-distribution

Player A and B participate in a match where the probability that A will win each point is $p$, for B its $1-p$ and a player wins when he reach $11$ points by a margin of $\ge2$

The outcome of the match is specified by $P(y|p, A_{wins})$. If we know that A wins, his score is specified by B's score; he has necessarily scored $max(11, y + 2)$ points

In the case of  $y\ge10$ we have

$P(A_{wins} \cap y|p) = \binom{10 + 10}{10}p^{10}(1-p)^{10}
   \cdot[2p(1-p)]^{y-10}\cdot p^2$

The elements represents respectively:

- probability of reaching *(10, 10)*
- probability of reaching *y* after *(10, 10)*
- probability of A winning two times in a row

I would like to change the constant $p$ assumption and draw $p$ from a beta distribution.

The first part can be rewritten as as [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) function:

$$ P(A_{wins} \cap y|\alpha, \beta) =\binom{10+10}{10}\frac{B(10+\alpha, 10+\beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \cdot \space _{...} \cdot \space _{...} $$

The second term contains an infinite series.
Is it possible to express this also in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

*Edit*

After the comment of @whuber I realised that during the second phase player A and player B are alternately winning a point and hence, $p = \alpha  \space/\space (\alpha + \beta)$ and $(1 - p) = \beta \space/\space (\alpha + \beta) $. Therefore, we can write

$$  2p(1-p)^{y-10}  = (2\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta})^{y-10} = (\frac{2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)(\alpha + \beta)})^{y-10}$$

Next,

$$ \sum^{z=\infty}_{z=0}r^{z}$$

where $z=y-10$ and $r=\frac{2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2}$

Because $r<1$, an infinite geometric series reduction applies and we can write

$$ \sum^{z=\infty}_{z=0}r^{z} = \frac{1}{1 - r} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2}}$$

We can multiply the result with the third term and obtain

$$  = \frac{(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta})^2}{1 - \frac{2\alpha\beta}{(\alpha + \beta)^2}} = \frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$$

Is the above derivation done correct?

Comment: Is $p$ drawn from a Beta prior and fixed for the entire match or is each point determined by an independent draw from that prior?

Comment: Ideally, the latter. Different for each point

Comment: I'm not seeing how that differs from the situation where the chance of winning each point is fixed at $\alpha/(\alpha+\beta).$

Comment: Ah do you mean that because in this phase both player A and player B score a point alternatively until they reach $y$, this probability doesn't change. It's a constant equal to $\alpha / (\alpha + \beta)$?

Comment: I think it comes down to independence.  Suppose $P_1,P_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of independent draws from a common Beta distribution. Let $X=X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ be a finite sequence of independent Bernoulli($P_i$) variables with densities $f_i$ and suppose $x=x_1,x_2,\ldots$ is any sequence of zeros and ones. Then $$\Pr(X=x)=\prod_i\Pr(X_1=x_1)=\prod_i\int_0^1E[\mathcal I(X_i=x_i)\mid P_i=p_i]f_i(p_i)\mathrm dp_i\\=\prod_{i\mid x_i=1}E[P_i]\prod_{i\mid x_i=0}(1-E[P_i]).$$ Thus, only the expectations of the $P_i$ play any role.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you check whether my derivation of the second term is correct?

Comment: Just to be sure about the notation: if A wins, $y$ is B's score?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.